# Electronic current

Tags: current

I am student in emebedded system engineering, In recent time I have leaned about the diode and transistor and about hole current and electron current, can I ask when we need to analyse the circuit use electron current and when we should not, I think every AC circuit in my house conect togerther and recive from a high gird voltage, can we analyse the single AC circuit in big circuit use electron current or it should use conventional current to follow the whole circuit, I dont know when we can use electron current and when we can not, if I follow all the circuit use CV current and when I want to think about the electron current, I should think about what circuit, just simple circuit and use conventional current in complicated circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Most electrical and electronic engineers and technicians use Conventional Current.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to work at the level of components, and schematics, and design things like LED flashers, radios, drones, phones, embedded systems, computers, power grids, power stations, anything from the smallest to the largest electrical or electronic artefact you can think of, then conventional current is all you need.

If you want to design the junctions of diodes or transistors themselves, or the semiconductor materials that they are made from, then you need to understand electron and hole currents, and a whole bunch more physics as well.

If you want a model to help you think about what's flowing and going on in a circuit, I strongly recommend the [hydraulic analogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_analogy) over electron flows, for several reasons.

- Those that try to reason from electrons have a hard time understanding potential, why a 12 V battery delivering 1 amp delivers 4 times the power that a 3 V battery delivering 1 amp does. With the hydraulic analogy, potential is baked right into the model as pressure or height in an intuitive way.
- You can build surprisingly complex circuits with hydraulics, resistors, diodes, capacitors, inductors, even a switch mode boost converter.
- The way engineers communicate, the schematic, embodies the hydraulic analogy. It conventionally shows high potentials/voltages at the top, reducing as we go down the page. If you think of charge as a fluid with mass, it will try to flow down the page.
- When you do come to drop it for something better, then it's easy to, as it's obviously completely [wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong) and non-physical, just a model. Wires are not pipes. Electrons sound tantalisingly real, but when you dig into the [Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model), it doesn't handle any of the quantum effects you would need to actually work with it for semiconductor design.
- The electron flow goes opposite to the way we have chosen conventional current to flow (sorry about that, but it's only a convention - [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/567/)). So trying to think about or work with electron flow for ordinary electronic design introduces confusion and grief when connecting red and black on 100% of DVMs, power supplies and electronic instruments out there.